# DAX formula to find MIN and % difference

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I need help with using correct DAX formula to find the minimum value in column and then evaluating each row value based off of that minimum (how much higher is each number in %).

My table looks as follows:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlRG3cDrsAZTgeF4aurEanDadvVa3w?e=NKWlRQ

I am trying to obtain results in third and fourth columns that are based off of second column.

Answer (score 2):

DAX calculated columns:

```
Minimum = MIN ( 'Table'[Sedan] )
```

```
% Difference = ( 'Table'[Sedan] - 'Table'[Minimum] ) / 'Table'[Sedan]
```

Make sure to set the column data format to % for the second.

Aggregate functions are not affected by row context, so when we define 'Table'[Minimum] it's just grabbing the whole-table min. Then, we can just use the newly calculated column in a simple % difference with the existing 'Table'[Sedan]. In row context, column references are the value for the current row.

**EDIT**: Per comments, the goal is for this to interact with filters, so it cannot be in a calculated column.

Measures below:

Your min will depend on how you're building your visuals and reports, which you haven't shared with us. Two versions below:

```
//v1
Minimum = MIN ( 'Table'[Sedan] )
```

```
//v2
Minimum = CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[Sedan] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ) )
```

And the % difference. Again this will depend on how you're building reports, which you haven't shared. The first version works with the first version above, assuming you're looking at many rows at a time and you want the average % difference:

```
//v1
% Difference =
VAR MinValue = [Minimum]
RETURN
  AVERAGEX (
    'Table',
    ( 'Table'[Sedan] - MinValue ) / MinValue
  )
```

With the second version, I assume you're putting 'Table'[Sedan] into a visual so you're seeing distinct values:

```
//v2
% Difference =
VAR CurrentSedan = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Sedan] )
VAR MinValue = [Minimum]
RETURN
  (CurrentSedan - MinValue) / MinValue
```

Comment: Hi Gregg, thank you for your reply. If I need minimum for the filtered data in column and not column in entire table, I just refer to the column name rather than 'table'[column]?

Comment: If you need this to interact with filters, then you don't need calculated columns, but measures. Editing currently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your solution gets the job done.